# Removing object from category

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category and $X\in \text{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$.

Now, let $\mathbf{C}'$ be $\mathbf{C}$ with $X$ and all the morphisms to and from $X$ removed, i.e. we get rid of all morphisms in $\text{Hom}(A,X)$ and in $\text{Hom}(X,B)$ for any $A,B\in\text{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$.

Is $\mathbf{C}'$ a category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The only thing that could conceivably go wrong in the definition of a category would be composition of morphisms, but if you only remove the morphisms that start or end with the object that you’re removing, you’re never going to have problems with composition.

Comment: Is this just not the full subcategory given by $\mathbf{C}'$?  Or is it more subtle than that?

Comment: @Randall I believe it is.